# iPhone NetworkReachability - Tethering is recognised as 3G and not WIFI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi, tethering

In my app i am trying to get network status using **NetworkReachability**. I tried it when i am under wifi or 3g connection and it works perfectly.

The problem is when i am connected to a *personal hotspot/tethering*(tested with iPhone to iPhone, Android to iPhone and routers with sim) i get always **3g connection** and not wifi.Tested with ios10. Is there any way without using private framework to control if i am under tethering connection or hotspot?

Comment: By your referring to NetworkReachability, nobody really knows what it exactly is.

Answer (score 0):

You have check Reachability for internet, Using following link to download Reachability demo project from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

,and add both .h and .m files to your project.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNetworkChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

- (void) handleNetworkChange:(NSNotification *)notice
{

  NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

   if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {NSLog(@"no");}
else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {NSLog(@"wifi"); }
else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {NSLog(@"cell"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [GitHub](https://github.com/), [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git) library provide the check the network Reachability status. Using the [Network Reachability Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#network-reachability-manager) object file to detect the status of internet reachability status.

**Shared Network Reachability**

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
}];

[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```